# How to avoid inconsistent capitalization of back references

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Let's say I'm citing journal articles as `@article` and working papers as `@rechreport` with `type = {Working Paper}`, as in the following MWE:

```
@techreport{liu2009role,
    title       = {The role of media in initial public offerings},
    author      = {Laura Liu and Ann E. Sherman and Yong Zhang},
    year        = {2009},
    type        = {Working Paper},
    institution = {DePaul University; Hong Kong University of Science and Technology},
    url         = {https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1737544}
}

@article{malkiel2013asset,
    author      = {Burton G. Malkiel},
    title       = {{Asset management fees and the growth of finance}},
    year        = {2013},
    journal     = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
    volume      = {27},
    number      = {2},
    pages       = {97--108},
    url         = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.27.2.97}
}
```

as `library.bib` with `biblatex` loaded as

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
    backref=true,
    indexing=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
```

This will render as follows:

[image]

Where “cited”, abbreviated as “cit.”/”Cit.” is once capitalized and once not capitalized. The behaviour appears to be caused by the fullstop following the URL in the `@techreport`, which does not exist in `@article`.

Is this expected behaviour and, if I don't like it, how can I avoid it? (e.g., how can I add a fullstop after the URL for the `@article` entry type, remove it from `@techreport` or change capitalization itself?

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/141

Answer (score 2):

The `techreport` driver is mapped to `misc`. The `misc` and `article` drivers have two different codes after the `addendum` field, respectively `\newunit\newblock` and `\setunit{\addspace}\newblock`. This code will correct the bug (or the feature):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}{\newunit\newblock
 \iftoggle{bbx:related}}{\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
 \iftoggle{bbx:related}}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @misc{liu2009role,
  title       = {The role of media in initial public offerings},
  author      = {Laura Liu and Ann E. Sherman and Yong Zhang},
  year        = {2009},
  type        = {Working Paper},
  institution = {DePaul University; Hong Kong University of Science and Technology},
  url         = {https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1737544}
 }
 
 @article{malkiel2013asset,
  author      = {Burton G. Malkiel},
  title       = {{Asset management fees and the growth of finance}},
  year        = {2013},
  journal     = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  volume      = {27},
  number      = {2},
  pages       = {97--108},
  url         = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.27.2.97}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
backref=true,
indexing=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}{\newunit\newblock
 \iftoggle{bbx:related}}{\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
 \iftoggle{bbx:related}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\cite{liu2009role}
\cite{malkiel2013asset}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

If you prefer the capitalization:

```
\xpatchbibdriver{article}{\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
 \iftoggle{bbx:related}}{\newunit\newblock
 \iftoggle{bbx:related}}{}{}
```

Of course, you have to check what the other drivers are doing to see if the correct behavior is uppercase or lowercase "cit.".